# Dropbox vs .DS_Store: prevent syncing

Tags: dropbox, macos

How to prevent Dropbox from syncing `.DS_Store` files on OS X?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or are you using a specific version of dropbox client on a specific OS and seeing files actually being uploaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Dropbox's help](https://www.dropbox.com/help/145/en), the `.DS_Store` files are not synchronised.

> ### Ignored files
>
> Some small system files aren't synced over Dropbox. These include:
>
> - desktop.ini
> - thumbs.db
> - .ds_store
> - icon\r
> - .dropbox
> - .dropbox.attr

If you want to manually delete all `.DS_Store` files, OS X Daily shared a how-to guide: [Delete All .DS_Store Files from Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/05/delete-all-ds-store-files-from-mac-os-x/).

Comment: Dropbox is no network connection in the sense of the KB-article! It does not apply there!

Comment: My icons are still showing as synced on OS X. Apparently and despite the green sign, these do not show up on the web site. [ Would be good if Dropbox used a different icon for these files to avoid confusion. ] On a side note, I wonder what to do if I wanted them to be synced.